# How to open files writen by spyder using command prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Win 10 user. I wrote a file (tik-tac-toe game) with spyder in anaconda. As I tried to run it with command prompt, I received "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application".

The modules I use are numpy, matplotlib and random. I used

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

which took quite a while. I'm not sure if there is an issue with the modules or other stuff.

Comment: I find it strange that tik-tac-toe would require all those modules. Please show the command you used to try to run it

Comment: @cricket_007 I just drag the file from the file explorer into the command prompt and hit enter

Comment: @MadisonCourto I have read that pose, but I don't understand what they are saying at all. My level is only using spyder to run simple models and other math stuff

Comment: What *file*? That's not how you run Python code anyway. You manually have to type `python game.py`, for example

Comment: @cricket_007 it's the .py file I drag. Dragging was successful when the python file contains only simple math (like calculating prime numbers before 100) But anyway, the method you provide works. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just drag the file from the file explorer into the command prompt and hit enter

I assume you dragged a `.py` file.

Those aren't executable processes like an exe. They must be interpreted by the Python interpreter, meaning that you'd have to type out `python game.py`, for example from that directory.

If you want to make an EXE, then you can search for options like pyinstaller or cx_freeze